# How to add the Em dash "—" to my keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, special-characters

I have an AZERTY keyboard, and an [ErgoDox keyboard](https://www.massdrop.com/buy/ergodox).
I can map all the keys I want to the Ergodox, and macros as well.

I'm looking for the `—`. This is [the Em dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Common_dashes); it is *different* from the "minus" of keypad (`-`<>`—`) which seems not "simply" accessible with the French layout.

How to display it using a keyboard (= not using the Alt 0151 combination)?

Comment: According to http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/ you're referring to the Em dash, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Common_dashes and http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014

Comment: Thank you, but if I try `Alt +2014` I get `Ì` not the `—`

Comment: 2014 is the hexadecimal code; 8212 is the decimal code you need for the Alt-Numpad trick. See the Wikipedia article for details.

Comment: `Alt +8212` gives me `¶`. But I found it here with your clue: http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=557434&langid=6

Comment: Try Alt+0151. To display it using the keyboard, you have to map it. And to do that, you have to use another key from the keyboard you don't usually use.

Comment: I found it here:http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=557434&langid=6 I need to do `Alt + 0151`. This is a macro and it doesn't seem possible to send it directly with a special key combination (which would be far easier to program on my Ergodox...)

Comment: Ah, indeed `Alt 0151` is documented on both links I gave too; some Windows character set value rather than a Unicode value, I guess. Note that the `Alt +8212` "syntax" often means you're typing *hexadecimal* Unicode codes, [where you're indeed really pressing the `+` as well](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm). Not sure what you were typing for the first tries exactly.

Comment: What is that "macro" you're referring too? Can you "program" keys with some sort of programming language?

Comment: @Arjan I can assign whatever I want of each key of my keyboard (this is a blank keyboard, I let you google for ergodox). So I would like to "program" one key so that when I press it, it sends the proper key combination to Windows and Windows "understands" it as "emdash".

Comment: It's clear what you want. But you're also writing "I can map all the keys I want to the Ergodox, and macros as well". What are those macros? That makes me think you can assign [sequences of instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macro_%28computer_science%29) to a single key. (And if true, then I wonder why it's so hard to create a macro that "writes" the Em dash.)

Comment: This depends on the way you program Ergodox.

Comment: @Arjan You're perfectly right: i can assign sequences of instructions to a single key, but there's a problem with the 'ALT' key when sending macros: if I try to do a macro that uses 'ALT' key, there's a bug that makes sending *more* than one key with 'ALT' pressed not working. And because I'm not an expert with this pure C program, I'm looking for a workaround that could send only one keystroke, or only **one** combination of 'ALT' + a key.

Comment: I guess you tried, but maybe you could copy the character and then paste it when creating the macro? (I think the keyboard macros need to generate key codes, not characters, but maybe when pasting a character some magic happens...)

Comment: You guessed right: this is just a huge bunch of macros that change the text into pure hexa values that are sent to the USB. So copy/paste doesn't work because it needs pre-defined macros (which are hex values) like 'A'..'Z', and '0'...'9' and some 'ALT' and other special keys.

Answer (score 2):

Download "[Keyboard Layout manager](http://www.klm32.com/)" which is a free software. Install it. Run it as an administrator.

[image]

Double click on your language.

[image]

Click on the key to which you want to assign the character.

[image]

Click on the character map, which is behind the current window.

[image]

In the subset, write 32 and click on the character shown in the picture. Close the window.

[image]

Click OK.

[image]

Close the window.

Restart your PC.

Comment: Unnecessarily complicated. Microsoft Keyboard Layout Generator lets you edit keyboard layouts more conveniently.

Comment: @Jukka, reading [some Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx) or [this blog post](http://littletinyfish.com/create-a-new-keyboard-layout-with-the-microsoft-keyboard-layout-creator/), seems to indicate that Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator requires one to build a DLL and an installation program to use that? (If true, then that does NOT seem more convenient to me, though I was surprised that the above answer requires one to restart Windows after making changes.)

Comment: @Arjan, MSKLC lets you enter a character by its Unicode number, and it does not require system restart.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you may also look into using an [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) script that will replace either `---` or a specific key combination with "—" The plus side of doing this is that it will interact relatively nicely if you have a number of other shortcuts you want to use (because they can all reside in AutoHotkey).

If you do install AutoHotkey, a script which would accomplish this would include the following line.

`::---::—`

This creates a **hotstring**, which will automatically replace the sequence `---` with `—` when typed and followed by a whitespace key like space or enter. AutoHotkey is very powerful and this is almost the simplest thing it can do, but that flexibility might be useful.

Comment: I've got a prebuilt executable version of this called [AutoDash](https://github.com/TurekBot/AutoDash/releases), which removes the need to install AutoHotkey, if anyone's interested in that.

Answer (score 0):

Bépo provide some caracters like theses :

```
– —
```

You can use the Bépo or learn information from the layout implementation and public source code of it.

You can also post the question in the bépo french forum.

Comment: What is “Bépo”?

Comment: Bépo is a french disposition for keyboard wich are build with a similar vision of the Dvorak layout.     
It’s clearly a layout completely different than Azerty.   

You can find information about it at http://bepo.fr